# Change Text on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so if I was doing a form, I could use:

```
<form method="get" action="">
<label for="textinput">Text:</label> 
<input type="text" value="" name="textinput" id="textinput" /> 
<input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Search" onclick="return changeText('submitbutton');" /> 
</form>
```

Then add this js:

```
function changeText(submitId){
    var submit = document.getElementById(submitId);
    submit.value = 'Working...';
    return false;
};
```

BUT my issue is my link is this:

```
<a id="sharelink" href="">Post to Here</a>
```

So wondering if ONCLICK of link ID > sharelink

I could show > working...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is `ShareButtonView`?  Are you using some library?  You should add a tag indicating which libraries besides jQuery you're using.

Comment: Well basically, that isnt really relevant. Because all I want to achieve, is changing the text Post to Here to Working ... ( onclick ) of the href link. Sharing the library has no benefit to the link text.

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed:

I added ...

```
<a id="sharelink"onclick="changeText(this)" href="">Post to Here</a>
```

And the script is:

```
function changeText(currentElement){
currentElement.firstChild.data="Working ...";
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should use

```
onclick="changeText('submitbutton');"
```

instead of

```
onclick="return changeText('submitbutton');"
```